# Cannot use this operation on a shared drive item. (line8, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using this script on multiple shared drive to start cleaning up these orphan files.  Below is the script.  Issue I started seeing on two of the drives is this "Cannot use this operation on a shared drive item."  Any ideas?

```
function collectOrphans(findOrphaned) {
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Orphaned').next();
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
var orphanCount = 0;
while(files.hasNext()){
  var file = files.next();
  if(!file.getParents().hasNext()){
    folder.addFile(file);
    orphanCount++;      
  }
}
Logger.log('Moved ' + orphanCount + ' orphans successfully.');
}"
```

Answer (score -1):

This specific error is being thrown because you are trying to add a reference to a file which lays in a shared drive from another, different drive folder (your personal drive or a different shared drive).

In order to overcome this, you could:

- Create an 'orphaned' folder for each of your drives, and repeat the function for each of them.
- Use only one 'orphaned' folder, but use [`makeCopy()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination) to copy the files to the folder rather than just creating a reference to each of them.

Additionally, in order to find orphaned files, you may want to check out using `is:unorganized` filter along with `DriveApp.searchFiles()` (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/40i5l3/lpt_use_the_filter_isunorganized_ownerme_in_your/)).